# Skrill BAD_REQUEST - Invalid parameter

Tags: html, skrill

I am trying to implement a quick payment form to my website for Skrill

I am getting the error

```
{"code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Invalid parameter"}
```

Here my form

```
<form action="https://pay.skrill.com/" method="post">
<input name="pay_to_email" type="hidden" value="myemail@hotmail.com">
<input name="recipient_description" type="hidden" value="example">
<input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="userid_datetime1">
<input name="return_url" type="hidden" value="http://www.example.com/PostNewPM.aspx?To=MyName">
<input name="return_url_text" type="hidden" value="Pm MyName">
<input name="return_url_target" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="cancel_url" type="hidden" value="http://www.example.com/Donate.aspx">
<input name="cancel_url_target" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="status_url" type="hidden" value="example@gmail.com">
<input name="dynamic_descriptor" type="hidden" value="example">
<input name="logo_url" type="hidden" value="https://www.example.com/logo_skrill.png">
<input name="language" type="hidden" value="EN">
<input name="confirmation_note" type="hidden" value="Do not forget to PM back MyName"> <span class="HowMuchDonate">How Much You Want To Donate (USD $):</span>
<input class="HowMuchDonate" maxlength="30" name="amount" style="width: 100px; text-align: center;" type="text">
<input name="currency" type="hidden" value="USD">
<input name="detail1_description" type="hidden" value="Donate example">
<input name="detail1_text" type="hidden" value="Do not forget to PM for rewards">
<input name="detail2_description" type="hidden" value="The player name to PM">
<input name="detail2_text" type="hidden" value="MyName">
<br>
<input name="Pay" type="submit" value="Pay">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use valid/real Merchant account into your "pay_to_email" parameter.

I would advise you to use some backend server-to-server requests to avoid end customer able to modify your HTML.

Comment: yes unfortunately this is correct. I learned it from their support. they require you to be a registered company in your country. this is total stupidness. paypal doesnt require such restriction. i just want to use their stupid api :( however paypal does not operate in Turkey anymore since they dont want to acquire licence